# TABLEAU Calculating a Running DISTINCT COUNT on usernames for last 3 months

Tags: tableau-api

**Issue:**

Need to show RUNNING DISTINCT users per 3-month interval^^. (See goal table as reference). However, “COUNTD” does not help even after table calculation or “WINDOW_COUNT” or “WINDOW_SUM” function.

*^^RUNNING DISTINCT user means DISTINCT users in a period of time (Jan - Mar, Feb – Apr, etc.). The COUNTD option only COUNT DISTINCT users in a window. This process should go over 3-month window to find the DISTINCT users.*

`Original Table

Date    Username
1/1/2016    A
1/1/2016    B
1/2/2016    C
2/1/2016    A
2/1/2016    B
2/2/2016    B
3/1/2016    B
3/1/2016    C
3/2/2016    D
4/1/2016    A
4/1/2016    C
4/2/2016    D
4/3/2016    F
5/1/2016    D
5/2/2016    F
6/1/2016    D
6/2/2016    F
6/3/2016    G
6/4/2016    H`

Goal Table 
[image]

**Tried Methods:**

**Step-by-step:** 
Tried to distribute the problem into steps, but due to columnar nature of tableau, I cannot successfully run COUNT or SUM (any aggregate command) on the LAST STEP of the solution.

**STEP 0** Raw Data

This tables show the structure Data, as it is in the original table.

**STEP 1** COUNT usernames by MONTH

The table show the count of users by month. You will notice because user B had 2 entries he is counted twice. In the next step we use DISTINCT COUNT to fix this issue.

**STEP 2**  DISTINCT COUNT by MONTH

Now we can see who all were present in a month, next step would be to see running DISTINCT COUNT by MONTH for 3 months

**STEP 3** RUNNING DISTINCT COUNT for 3 months

Now we can see the SUM of DISTINCT COUNT of usernames for running 3 months. If you turn the MONTH INTERVAL to 1 from 3, you can see STEP 2 table.

**LAST STEP** Issue Step

GOAL: Need the GRAND TOTAL to be the SUM of MONTH column.

Request:

I want to calculate the SUM of '1' by MONTH. However, I am using WINDOW function and aggregating the data that gave me an Error.

WHAT I NEED

`Jan    Feb     March    April    May   Jun
  3      3        4        5       5     6`

WHAT I GOT

`Jan    Feb    March      April    May    Jun
  1       1       1          1       1      1`

**My Output after tried methods:**  Attached twbx file. DISTINCT_count_running_v1

**HELP taken:**

- https://community.tableau.com/thread/119179 ; Tried this method but stuck at last step
- https://community.tableau.com/thread/122852 ; Used some parts of this solution

Comment: Your problem was solved in this issue? If yes, please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached the problem was identifying the minimum login date for each user and then using that date to count the distinct number of users. For example, I have [data in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IpMT.png). I created a calculated field called Min User Login Date as { FIXED [User]:MIN([Date])} and then did a CNTD(USER) on Min User Login Date to get the [unique user count by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcBcq.png). If you want running total, then you can do quick table calculation on Running Total on CNTD(USER) field.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put Month(date) and count(username) in the columns then you will get result what you expect. 
See screen below
[image]